# What was the music playing at background at 13:58 in episode 2 of Your lie in April?

Tags: music, your-lie-in-april

What was the music playing in the background at 13:58 in episode 2 of *Your lie in April*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an original song made for this anime called "Kimi wa Haru no Naka ni Iru" (You Exist in Spring).

[Link to song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cfe44kMDfDo)

Comment: Damn, listening to this song made me overcome with all the feels again -_-